# How do I use an if statement if the value it has to scan is a letter?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a code that uses letters for choices, like a quiz.
I can't understand how to put letters in the if statement though.
This is the code I'm trying to do.

```
if (choice == "A") {
    //true
} else if (choice == "B") {
    //false
}
```

Sorry because I'm quite new to java.

Comment: If `choice` is a character than use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: If they are strings, then use "A".equals(choice).